# Reference for first appearance of Samelson product

Tags: homotopy-theory, loop-spaces, higher-homotopy-groups

Samelson noticed that the commutator in any based loop space induced the *Pontrjagin product* on the homology of that loop space. What is the original reference where the name Samelson product is attached to  the map on homotopy groups induced by that commutator?

Comment: Samelson's original paper was published 1953. Whitehead discusses the product on the level of homotopy groups in his 1954 paper *On Mappings into Grouplike Spaces*. Whitehead attributes the construction to Samelson and introduces the angular bracket notation, but (as far as I can see) declines to give it a specific name. My guess is that the term *Samelson product* come from either I. James or R. Bott. Both have papers appearing in the late '50s in which the it appears. (see eg. James-Thomas *Which Lie Groups are Homotopy Abelian*).

Comment: Tyrone, many thanks

Comment: Do yu have a title for Samelson's paper? probably something I've heard of but with a title that gave me no clue

Comment: Thanks to you giving the date, I found it - the related homology is in the title

Comment: Jim, the paper I found is [A connection between the Whitehead and the Pontryagin product](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2372549.pdf), Amer. J. Math. **75** (1953), 744-752. I'm glad if this was helpful to you.

Comment: yes, exactly - seems he was interested in the image by Hurewicz map, so didn't even name his product